# Whats the real time example of dynamic polymorphism in java

Tags: java, dynamic, polymorphism

What is the real time example of dynamic polymorphism in java?

I have been asked so many places this question in interview 
but dint got real answer. Code:

```
class A {
    public void m1() {}
}

class B extends A {
    public void m1() {}
}

class manage {
    A a1 = new A();
    B b1 = new B();
    A a2 = new B();

    //when i will call A's m1 it will call m1 of A
    a1.m1();

    //when i will call B's m1 it will call  m1 of B
    b1.m1();

    //when i will call B's m1
    a2.m1();

}
```

in the above code by looking , i can say its whose object will be called then why its run time polymorphism

**Anyone can please help the real time correct example of runtime/dynamic polymorphism  ??**

Comment: And, of course: the above code won't even compile, as you cant have these method calls just sitting in the body of that class. Avoid doing that: when putting up "real code", make sure it *compiles*. Anything else will quickly mislead your readers, resulting in negative feedback.

Comment: Thanks for editing it .. I will keep in the mind code formatting and compilation of code next time on wards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets change your code example just a little bit. Instead of having a test class that defines the objects to test, we only offer a method taking some arguments:

```
public void testCalls(A a1, A b1, A b2) {
  a1.m1();
...
```

Now, can you still say what will happen? "Hmm, that will depend on what gets passed to the method call?!"

In your example, you know what is going to happen because you can easily deduct the *true* nature of all objects. But what if you don't have that information? When you are only providing an interface, and the incoming objects aren't showing up in your source code?!

Thus: what matters is the *true* type of an object at runtime. Of course, when you *construct* a simple example, you always know that true type. But the things that matter in the real world are simply not that simple.

Comment: Can you please place an full example for better understanding ..   I got it that little complicated example will help, but I am looking for the same . a better example which can give me lots of understanding ..

Comment: I can't promise I can do that before Monday. Please drop me a comment in case you don't hear from me by Tuesday or so!

Comment: Hi Ghostcat,  As we discussed  I am waiting for response

Answer (score 1):

`"Dynamic polymorphism is the polymorphism existed at run-time"`.

That mean Java compiler does not understand which method is called at compilation time. Only JVM decides which method is called at run-time.

In your example, the compiler don't know the behavior of `a2.m1()`. However, at the runtime, the JVM will invoke the code which was defined in the class B.

```
class A {
    public void m1(){
        System.out.println("Inside A's m1 method");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    // overriding m1()
     public void m1(){
            System.out.println("Inside B's m1 method");
     }
}

class C extends A {
     public void m1(){
            System.out.println("Inside C's m1 method");
     }
}
// Driver class
class Dispatch {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // object of type A
        A a = new A();
        a.m1(); // calling m1 of A

        a = new B();
        a.m1(); // calling m1 of B

        a = new C();
        a.m1(); // calling m1 of C

    }
}
```

Results:

`Inside A's m1 method
Inside B's m1 method
Inside C's m1 method`

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, it happens in realtime aka runtime.